# Working with non generic parts of a generic interface

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, interface

consider the following code:

```
public interface IStuff<T>
{
    IList<T> Items { get; set; }
    bool IsExpanded { get; set; }
}

public interface IBar
{
    string Name { get; set; }
}

public interface IFoo : IBar, IStuff<IBar>
{
}

public class MyClass : IFoo 
{
    public Name {get;set;
    public IList<IBar> Items { get; set;}
    bool IsExpanded { get; set; }
}
```

When I use this, what I'm actually going to do, is populate `MyClass.Items` with instances of `IFoo`, this is allowed as `IFoo` implements `IBar`, so all is good.

However there is a method that I'm working inside a control, which does not know and should not know about `IBar`.  It only needs to know about `IStuff<>` Specifically that there is a list and a property.

When I'm working with the `Items`, I'm going to detect if the item implements `IStuff` like this.

```
public void ProcessItems( object item )
{
    IStuff<object> stuff = item as IStuff<object>;
    stuff.IsExpanded = true;
    foreach( var childItem in stuff.items )
    {
        ProcessItems( childItem );
    }
}
```

The problem here, is the cast into `IStuff<object>` does not work now, it returns null.
What I want to do is work with the generic part of the interface only, I don't care about what the `T` is.

The question is how do I replace

```
IStuff<object> stuff = item as IStuff<object>;
```

so that I can work with the items declared in the `IStuff<>` interface?

Comment: Perhaps you should split your interface up into two, one generic and one non-generic version of it, where the generic version inherits from the non-generic one. Then you could use the objects without knowing the `<T>`, but of course you would only be able to access the things not needing a `T`.

Comment: @HimBromBeere fixed that for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you need [co-variance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd799517(v=vs.110).aspx) on your interface `IStuff`. However as `IList<T>` is not co-variant you may use an interface that supports covariance such as `IEnumerable<T>` which *is* co-variant since .NET 4.0:

```
public interface IStuff<out T>
{
    IEnumerable<T> Items { get; set; }
    bool IsExpanded { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can cast a an instance of `IStuff<IBar>` to `IStuff<object>`.

Comment: This is promising, The interface looks ok at the moment, however, I cannot change MyClass to declare IEnumerable.  It has to be a List.  This is because there is another implementation which I've not mentioned that requires a list.  Also I need to be able to add the items and so on.

Comment: But yould could implement that interface on the class and redirect to `MyClass.Items` so you have both `IStuff.Items` which returns an `IEnumerable<T>` and needs to be declared explicitely and `MyClass.Items` which returns an `IList<T>`. This won´t change the API of `MyClass`, it will enahce it by the changed interface.

Comment: I'm still looking at this, looking very promising.  Just there's alot of other code that is implementing ICollection that I need to modify to be able to compile.  I also like that the collection will end up wrapped in the class.

Comment: Maybe you could create a new interface that supports the `IEnumerable` and implement both the `IFoo`-interface and the new one on your class. Of course the implementation of the new interface on the class simply redirects to the already existing method.

Comment: using the IStuff<out T> works perfectly.   I've got to the items now, so should can work with the IsExpanded and items as well as the other things that I'm going to add to the interface.  I love that reflection isn't needed in this solution as well.

Answer (score 0):

Can you split `IStuff` into a non-generic and generic parts (that inherits from the non-generic part) and then only deal with the non-generic part in your code?  E.g.

```
public interface IStuff
{
    IsExpanded { get; set; }
}
public interface IStuff<T> : IStuff
{
    IList<T> Items { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't do this.  What I'm trying to do is work with the IStuff<> inside a control for a treeview, the Items, is going to be the part that links down to to the children.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind reflection, you could read the property and cast it to `IEnumerable`:

```
var listType = item.GetType().GetProperty("Items");
var enumerable = (IEnumerable)(listType.GetValue(item));
```

Likewise you could set the expanded flag.

Comment: The question is rather on casting an instance *within* the collection to the generic interface `IStuff`.

Comment: @HimBromBeere But he asked how he can replace the cast to work with objects within the List. But I am also curious for a better solution.